# Displaying amount of users on a webpage

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a PHP script that will count the amount of users that have visited the page within the last 10 minutes. This is my script right now:

```
function getOnlineUsers($database, $main_connection){

    $database;

    $visitor_id = session_id();

    $timestamp = time();
    $timeOut = $timestamp - 6000;

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO online (m_time, ip) VALUES ('$timestamp', '$visitor_id')", $main_connection);
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM online WHERE m_time < $timeOut");

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM online");
    mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    if(!$result){
        $online_users = 1;
    }else{
        $online_users = mysql_num_rows($result);
    }

    return $online_users+1;
}
```

The problem is that nothing is being inserted into the database and the database remains empty and therefore the count is null. Can someone please assist me in this?

Comment: Did you start session in this page?

Comment: Yes, it is the first php line so I didn't include it in the question.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using

Comment: I am using PHP 5.2 fastCGI

Comment: cron will be helpful in this....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, better use PDO or MySQLi. In your database, the 'm_time' column must be integer type, and pass the `$timestamp` value as number, not within quotes.

```
"INSERT INTO online (m_time, ip) VALUES ($timestamp, '$visitor_id')"
```

Comment: Thankyou, this worked perfectly. All I had to do was remove the quotation marks from $timestamp and change the datatype of m_time to int. Cheers!

Comment: I am having trouble deleting the old records. Can you help with this?

Answer (score 1):

1) Change '$timestamp' to NOW(), mysql can't understand php's time() function ( assuming m_time is a datetime field) .

ie:

```
INSERT INTO online (m_time, ip) 
 VALUES ( NOW(), '$visitor_id')
```

2) Your delete suffers the same problem

3) You can use something a little more clever to get the users in the last 10 minutes, try something like:

```
select count(*) AS OnlineUserCount 
 from online 
WHERE 
 m_time > DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE ) ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code looks fine ..   what i suggest you do is  echo out the query  when it runs and cope and paste it and  run it directly from phpmyadmin and check if it  gives you any error and if the  row  is inserted succesfully i suggest you check your connection file with the database.

And also  try what's  suggested by CoursesWeb